# How to save bitmap in new folder in DCIM to show it in gallery on cellphone (the cellphone doesn't have SDCard)?

Tags: java, android

I have an URL, I download the image in it and convert it to bitmap. I want to download the bitmap in the internal memory of the cellphone to be in the gallery. I found solutions but includes SDcard and I need to save the image even if the cellphone doesn't have external memory. How can I achieve that?

Comment: use internal memory

Comment: You can just create that directory first  and then put your file in it. What is the problem? Do not first create a bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not all cam app store on DCIM but you can

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                getContentResolver(), bitmap,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg", "DESCRIPTION HERE");
```

Comment: Thanks for that, is there a possibility to change directory like DCIM/newCarpet/image.jpg or creating a carpet inside the cellphone?

Comment: Of course. Depending on Android version use column .RELATIVE_PATH. But you have a file. Not a bitmap.